# Selecting attributes with Hyphen in chrome developer tool using xpath

Tags: xpath, google-chrome-devtools

How can I find the nodes that are `@is-visible = 'true'` using xpath in the document below? Essentially, how can I escape the hyphen

```xml
<root>
  <year is-visible = 'true'>November 2020</year>
  <year ishidden = 'true'>October 1998</year>
</root>
```

Comment: Works for me, there's no need to escape it.

Comment: In chrome? Double checked and it does not work for me in Chrome

Comment: https://puu.sh/GzE8w/60d52f75ac.png - ditto via console: `$x("//*[@is-visible='true']")`